# Ошибка TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import random
a=0
stra=str(a)
while True:
    name="name",stra
    int(stra)
    stra=a+1
    d = open(name, "w")
    d.write("Ха , мини-вирус")
    d.close()
    chislo=random.randint(1,9)
    chislo_pl=int(input("Угадая число от 1,9:"))
    
    if chislo==chislo_pl:
        print("молодец")
    if chislo<chislo_pl or chislo>chislo_pl:
        print("неправильно")
    str(stra)
```

Comment: `name="name",stra` — что вы хотели сделать этой строкой?

Comment: d = open(name, "w") ожидает строку, а вы ему кортеж передаёте.

Comment: ``int(stra)`` — это бессмысленная строчка.

Comment: Растет мини черный хакер XD

Comment: Для таких целей проще батник написать;))

Answer (score 0):

`name="name",stra` не правильная конкатенация!

попробуй `name = 'name' + stra`

Answer (score 0):

```py
    name="name",stra  <-- теперь в name кортеж!
    int(stra)         <-- а этот код никуда не записывает результат
```

Судя по логике, тут должно было быть так, чтобы значения переменных были подходящими для дальнейшего кода:

```py
    name="name"
    stra=int(stra)
```

Хотя тут, конечно, весь код странный. )